# How to pass mapped array to PageMethods?

Tags: c#, jquery, arrays, pagemethods

I've been trying to pass a data array to c# web method with using jquery. I have a table which has selectable rows. And my function must pass the id's of selected data. But i can't pass the object array with PageMethods.
Here is my jquery function;

```
function DeleteQuestions()
    {
        var table = $('#questTable').DataTable();
        var data = (table.rows('.selected').data()).map(function (d) { return d.q_id; });
        PageMethods.Delete(data);
    }
```

When i debug it with firebug, veriable data looks like : Object["543","544","546"] as i wanted. 
And here is my Web Method:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void Delete(List<string> questId)
    {
        DB_UserControl carrier = new DB_UserControl(); //break pointed here
    }//and looks it doesn't come here
```

It doesn't work, and the error is : **Cannot serialize object with cyclic reference within child properties.** I've searced for error but i couldn't figured it out. So need some help. Thanks in advance.

Note:Error throws at script function's last line: `PageMethods.Delete(data);` 
And i think it might be about mapped data causes some kind of loop behavior.

Comment: You need to post the `DB_UserControl`

Comment: I don't think so, because there is no function of it, it's just for test. And debug does not work in there. Error throws in jquery function.

Comment: So that information would have been good in the question... Why have you posted the c# code if the error is in DeleteQuestions..

Comment: Because i thought it could be good sharing what type is my web method's parameter.

Comment: We need more information about the error that throws, what line does it through on, can you recreate this in accordance with these [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with changing syntax. I use

```
var data = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (d) {
            return d.q_id;
        });
```

instead of given line. I don't know what caused the error but this code works fine and i get data in c#. Thank you all